# Adjective meaning "dependent on warfare or plunder"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm struggling to remember a word I've seen only once before that characterizes something (such as an economy) as being dependent upon or driven by resources gained through conquest.

The context in which I noticed it said something along the lines of "The Roman empire was doomed to collapse, in part, because of its ___ economy".

Comment: I found a couple of references to [***conquestorial capitalism**.*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22conquestorial+capitalism%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22conquestorial+capitalism%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3425j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Maybe just ***imperialist**?*

Comment: Those occured to me as well, but I specifically remember the word being novel to me. Not being able to recall it is killing me

Comment: Maybe **hegemonic**?

Comment: How about parasitic?  (Some economies with outsize military expenditures, e.g., 20th c. Sov. Union, survive on raw materials--oil, gas, gold, diamonds).

Comment: I've seen *warfare economy, permanent warfare economy, war-based economy, war-driven economy.*  But that doesn't seem to match up perfectly with your description.  I wonder if you could get this moved over to Economics SE.

Comment: "Military conquest" is defined on Wikipedia's page by that name as follows: "Conquest is the occupying of a country that is in need of rebuilding and it can involve the act of military as well as subjugation of an enemy by force of arms."  That is about as juvenile (as well as blaming the victim") as anything I have seen there.  "Predatory" may be a useful word for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**Raubwirtschaft** (from the German for "plunder economy") is perhaps the closest term, although it's not very common in English.

Wikipedia describes it as a colonialist state "where the whole economy of the state is based on robbery, looting and plundering the conquered territories", and gives the example of the historian [Arnold Toynbee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_J._Toynbee) describing the Roman Empire in this way. ([Wikipedia article on kleptocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptocracy)).

Robert Costanza suggests the term was coined by the German geographer and anarcho-pacifist thinker [Ernst Friedrich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Friedrich) in the early 20th century; today the term is often used in environmentalist discourse. See *Ecological Economics: The Science and Management of Sustainability*, Robert Costanza, 1992, p 121 ([Google Books link which doesn't always work](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Ecological_Economics/3b43BAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Raubwirtschaft&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover))

Kleptocracy is a related term, meaning literally government by thieves, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptocracy) usually refers to governments that steal from their own people rather than from others.

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not an exact match for what you are looking for, I like the word ***mercenary***.

While the word is used in a more exacting sense to denote a quasi-soldier who is in the business of war for the money, Rome's economy was made possible in large part because of the power of their military to subjugate people and then exact taxes from them.

Comment: It works as an adjective - possibly metaphoric - as well as the noun for the paid soldier. This would be my choice, too.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere: Thanks! Don

Answer (score 0):

**Partisan politics?** possibly? A firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person. especially : one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance. Political partisans who see only one side of the problem.

The term was coined by Vladimir Lenin in 1895, responding to Peter Struve, to counter what he considered to be the futility of objectivity in political, economic analysis. Class interests and material conditions of existence determine ideology, and thus, in a Marxist-Leninist view, true objectivity (in terms of non-partisanship) is not possible in a society of antagonistic classes.

Marxists, in Lenin's view, should openly acknowledge their partisanship on the side of proletarian revolution. Bourgeois emphasis on the normative goal of objectivity is thus considered delusional. In this sense, partitionist' is a universal and inevitable element of political and ideological life. Still, its presence is not always acknowledged or flatly denied by the ruling class.